# How do I combine rows?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
C1 | C2 | C3
---+----+---
X1 | Y1 | Z1
X1 | Y2 | Z2
X2 | Y3 | Z3
X2 | Y4 | Z4
X3 | Y5 | Z5
X3 | Y6 | Z6
```

and I'd like to merge rows to get:

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9
---+----+----+---+-----+----+----+----+---
X1 | Y1 | Z1 | X2 | Y3 | Z3 | X3 | Y5 | Z5
X1 | Y2 | Z2 | X2 | Y4 | Z4 | X3 | Y6 | Z6
```

Is there a smart and generic way to do it ?
Otherwise, I think I'm going to assign temp sequence number to each Xi, and then join on them to preserve the ordering.

My data model is perfectly fine with the 3 columns layout, but I need to output it 3 by 3 in CSV to another program.

Comment: Provide the name of you database server (oracle, mysql, mssql, etc.), In one database there might be features that is not available in others.

Comment: No there is no generic way. RDBMS are all about relations, but the rows that you combine are not related to each other. I suggest you use a programming language for this. (But it would be possible with SQL depending on what techniques the dbms offers.)

Comment: What is the rule for combining X1/Y1/Z1 with X2/Y3/Z3 etc.  Is it just the ordingal position of C1's value i.e. "first X1 with first X2 with first X3"?  Will there ever be an X4?  Where would that go in your output?  If there's a third X1 would that cause a third row in the output?  Would a matching third X2 and X3 be guaranteed in this circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You will join the same table three times and have to identify them by aliases.

```
SELECT MT1.value1 AS C1,MT1.value2 AS C2,MT1.value3 AS C3,
  MT2.value1 AS C4,MT2.value2 AS C5,MT2.value3 AS C6,
  MT3.value1 AS C7,MT3.value2 AS C8,MT3.value3 AS C9 FROM MY_TABLE MT1
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE MT2 ON (MT1.id = MT2.id AND MT2.C1='X2')
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE MT3 ON (MT2.id = MT3.id AND MT3.C1='X3')
WHERE MT1.C1='X1'
```

Think:

First you need to add the columns by left join. You will have 3^9 columns.

Then, add the conditions for joining only where the C1/C2/C3 differs (in X1,X2,X3)

Finally reduce the results to the first column='X1'.

Comment: And where is `id` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

The only "generic" way I can think of requires knowing the X and Y values:

```
select max(c1) as c1, max(c2) as c2, max(c3) as c3,
       max(c4) as c4, max(c5) as c5, max(c6) as c6,
       max(c7) as c7, max(c8) as c8, max(c9) as c9      
from ((select c1 as x, c2 as y, c1, c2, c3, NULL as c4, NULL as c5, NULL as c6, NULL as c7, NULL as c8, NULL as c9
       from table
       where c1 = 'x1'
      ) union all
      (select c1 as x, c2 as y, NULL, NULL, NULL, c1 as c4, c2 as c5, c3 as c6, NULL as c7, NULL as c8, NULL as c9
       from table
       where c1 = 'x2'
      ) union all
      (select c1 as x, c2 as y, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL as c4, NULL as c5, NULL as c6, c1 as c7, c2 as c8, c3 as c9
       from table
       where c1 = 'x3'
      )
     ) t
group by x, y;
```

In any particular database, there is probably a more generic solution, where (for instance) you don't have to guarantee that the values in `col2` are different.  However, this solution should work for the data as asked in the question and it is generic in the sense of being standard SQL.